# Can't login while data is true and login button seems doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, authentication

I make authentication app which is register and login with email and password using django and when I run my app the button login is not responding and then back to login page

I have tried to create new account and it saved on database (I use DBBrowser SqLite app) but when I want to do login then the login button is not working

this is views.py

```
def login_request(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = FormPengguna(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, "Berhasil Login")
            return redirect("halaman_utama:homepage")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Email/Password Salah!")
form = FormPengguna()
print(request.POST)
return render(request=request, template_name="masuk.html", context={"form": form})
```

this is html code

```
<form method="POST" action="/login_request" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form.email }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form.password }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <br><br><br>
    <p class="text-center">Forgot Password? <a href="/password_reset_request">Click Here</a>.</p>
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you say the login button isn't working?

Comment: If you are getting the "Email/Password Salah!" error it seems to be because if form.is_valid() is false. Try to print(form) in the else, just above the messages call

Comment: @ArunT no error show when button is not working

Comment: @Arnaud ok thank you will try once